# change just text in li that contains img

Tags: jquery

I have this html code

```
<ul class="criteria">
<li id="1">
criteria 1
<img id="1" class="save_criterion" src="../images/icons/add-icon-2.png">
<img id="1" class="delete_criterion" src="../images/icons/icon_delete_16x16.png">
</li>
<li id="2">
criteria 2
<img id="2" class="save_criterion" src="../images/icons/add-icon-2.png">
<img id="2" class="delete_criterion" src="../images/icons/icon_delete_16x16.png">
</li>
</ul>
```

I have function to change li text dynamically

```
$("input#criterion_name").live("keyup",function(e){
    var newText =  $("input#criterion_name").val();
    if(newText){
    $("ul.criteria > li.selected").html(newText);
    }
    else{
    // can't leave the text filed empty 
    $("#criterion_name").addClass("error"); 
}
```

the problem is when I type text in the input text, the images in li elements removed.
I want just to change the text in li element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the text in its own element, like a `span`. Then you can target that like this:

```
$("ul.criteria > li.selected > span.thetext").html(newText);
```

Also, an id attribute should not be only numbers and should not be used more than once in a document, i.e. it should be unique. You have several instances where `id="1"`

Comment: HTML5 allows for numerical IDs. HTML 4 did not, although most browsers ignored this and understood them anyway.

Answer (score 4):

use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

**EDIT**

```
$(".criteria > li").contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3}).first().replaceWith(newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the name inside the `li` in a `span` (or whatever element you feel that works).  Then change the `span`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLPya/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="criterion_name" />

<ul class="criteria">
    <li id="1">
        <span class="criteria_name">criteria 1</span>
        <img id="1" class="save_criterion" src="../images/icons/add-icon-2.png">
        <img id="1" class="delete_criterion" src="../images/icons/icon_delete_16x16.png">
    </li>
    <li id="2">
        <span class="criteria_name">criteria 2</span>
        <img id="2" class="save_criterion" src="../images/icons/add-icon-2.png">
        <img id="2" class="delete_criterion" src="../images/icons/icon_delete_16x16.png">
    </li>
</ul>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#criterion_name').keyup(function() {
    var newText = $(this).val();
    if (newText) {
        $('#1 span.criteria_name').html(newText);
    }
});​
```

Based on your selectors, your HTML wasn't complete, so I just added a text box and am changing the name of the first `li`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **nodeType** property to only select the text and replace it.. No need of encasing its value in a span..

Try this code

```
$("ul.criteria > li").contents().filter(function() {
      return (this.nodeType != 1 && this.textContent != '\n')
}).replaceWith('Older Text replaced...');
​
```

- Using the `.contents()` to get all the content inside the li.
- Then filtering and selecting only text nodes which has no carriage
  return..
- Then replace with new text

**[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ueabw/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Andy's answer because it additionally allows you to further manipulate that span.

So your HTML code would become:

```
<ul class="criteria">
  <li id="1">
    <span class="label_text">criteria 1</span> <!-- wrap in span.label_text -->
    <img id="1" class="save_criterion" src="../images/icons/add-icon-2.png">
    <img id="1" class="delete_criterion" src="../images/icons/icon_delete_16x16.png">
  </li>
  <li id="2">
    <span class="label_text">criteria 2</span> <!-- wrap in span.label_text -->
    <img id="2" class="save_criterion" src="../images/icons/add-icon-2.png">
   <img id="2" class="delete_criterion" src="../images/icons/icon_delete_16x16.png">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Since element IDs must be [unique within the HTML document](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp), and [looking up by ID is the fastest jQuery selector](http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19), there is no need to select by element type *and* ID.  The "[.live() method is deprecated,](http://api.jquery.com/live/)"; we're advised to use the .on() method instead. So, when we add in Andy's solution, your jQuery would become:

```
$('#criterion_name').on('keyup', function() {
    var newText =  $(this).val();
    if(newText.length){
      $('ul.criteria > li > span.label_text').html(newText);
    }
    else{
      // can't leave the text filed empty 
      $('#criterion_name').addClass('error');
    }
});​
```

[See my fiddle for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/wLnRC/).