# How to change the text of li in ul without changing it's other properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a `li` in a ul like following.

```
<li class="list-group-item" data_id="1909" id="1909"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1909" name="Navigate Window">Navigate Window</li>
```

I tried to change a text of this `li` with the following code.

```
$('#list1 #' + selectedId).text('abcd');
```

Using this code, the text is changing fine. But it losts the `input` inside the `li`. How do I prevent the replacing whole `li`?

And also I tried with the following in stackoverflow.
[change just text in li that contains img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863437/change-just-text-in-li-that-contains-img)

And i tried it like following,

```
$("ul.list-group > li.list-group-item > span.thetext").html('abcd');
```

My `ul` class is `list-group`. But i failed. How can do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to wrap the text within a `span` then change the contents of the span using a selector like

```js
var selectedId = '1909';
$('#list1 #' + selectedId + ' span').text('abcd');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li class="list-group-item" data_id="1909" id="1909"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1909" name="Navigate Window"><span>Navigate Window</span></li>
</ul>
```

If that is not possible, then based on your markup, you need to change the contents of the last child of your `li` so

```js
var selectedId = '1909';
$('#list1 #' + selectedId).contents().last().text('abcd');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li class="list-group-item" data_id="1909" id="1909"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1909" name="Navigate Window"><span>Navigate Window</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think adding a span is the best. Thanks alot again

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.append()` and wrap the text inside `span` as shown  :

```
 $('#list1 #' + selectedId).append('<span>abcd</span>');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uoph7hgh/1/)

Comment: This also worked for me for changing the text to include a count by each list item.  Thanks!